# Check if array element has certain format

Tags: javascript

I have an array with elements. These elements are object paths. Some are just one level deep : `ui.main` and some are multiple levels deep : `ui.main.tab.` Now my intention is to perform an action whenever the path is just one level deep.

so for example `ui.main => perform action.`   `ui.tab.main => do nothing` etc.

I know i have to use some sort of loop and a regular expression, but i am having trouble combining the two as i am not comfortable working with those.

Comment: By elements, do you mean strings? `['foo.bar', 'foo.bar.baz']`?

Comment: Yes sorry, the elements are basically strings as in your example @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string on the `.` and check the length:

```js
const arr = ['ui.main.tab', 'ui.main', 'test.main', 'test.main.tab'];

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (el.split('.').length === 2) console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd check whether the `indexOf` a `.` is the same as the `lastIndexOf` a `.` (and is not `-1`), fulfilling the condition when there's exactly one `.` in the string being checked:

```js
const arr = ['ui.main', 'ui.tab.main'];
arr.forEach((str) => {
  const index = str.indexOf('.');
  if (index !== -1 && str.lastIndexOf('.') === index) {
    console.log('doing something', str);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = ['ui.main', 'ui.tab.main', 'ui.foo'];

arr.forEach((str) => {
  const count = (str.match(/\./g) || []).length;
  if (count === 1) {
 console.log("do something with: " + str);
  }
});
```